# Windows Workflow Foundation 4 (WF4) Arguments

Tags: windows, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, arguments

I am working on a WF4 project for manager's to approve requests made to them for resources needed.  I and am passing in an argument of a custom type, a class called "Request".  The Request class contains a List of type Player where "Player" is another class I've created to represent the approving manager.  I'm using the DataContract Serializer on both classes to serialize them, and everything works fine with one problem.  In the workflow, if I try to update the Request class, or the List of Player collection with the Player that actually performed the approval, my workflow terminates and the record gets removed from the InstancesTable in my persistence database.  Does anyone know why this happens?  I'm thinking there has to be a way to dynamically update objects passed in to the workflow, but I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like there is some exception that is the result of updating the object that killing your workflow. If you are using the WorkflowApplication try adding a callback to the OnUnhandledException and check the UnhandledException to see what the problem is.